# Server http://localhost:8081 requires username and password

Tags: tomcat, servlets, localhost

[I am trying to access localhost:8080 but it is showing me I need to enter user name and password.I tried to enter the password that I was playing with but non of those are working. Is there anyway I could get out of this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POuEo.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with basic authentication in your Tomcat server. so there is a password required in this URL endpoint.

You can see conf/tomcat-user.xml and find user tags like this.

```
<user username="kevin" password="kevin" roles="role01"/>
```

the username and password are in the tag and check if there is a typo in the attribute.

for more information see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html)